# Swift - UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

It is a UITableView for audio playlists

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class TableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var tableData = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return self.tableData.collections.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

    var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    let playlist: MPMediaPlaylist = tableData.collections[indexPath.row] as MPMediaPlaylist
    let playlistName = playlist.valueForProperty(MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName) as NSString
    cell.textLabel?.text = playlistName

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
}
}
```

how to change it, to have an Albums in TableView?

i tryed to change  `var tableData = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery()`

to `var tableData = MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery()`

but it is not correct, xcode gives me an error: 0x1002364b0:  brk    #1

Comment: Check where you have assigned your tableView's delegate (Interface Builder?). It is set to a UIView instance, not your view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have done is a good start, changing `tableData` to the result of `MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery` instead of `MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery`. However, look in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, specifically the following three lines, where the contents of each cell are defined:

```
let playlist: MPMediaPlaylist = tableData.collections[indexPath.row] as MPMediaPlaylist
let playlistName = playlist.valueForProperty(MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName) as NSString
cell.textLabel?.text = playlistName
```

This code anticipates that `tableData` contains a collections property containing `MPMediaPlaylist` objects but the [`MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MPMediaQuery/albumsQuery) method returns a [`MPMediaQuery`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/MPMediaQuery) object with a collections property that contains an [`MPMediaItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/) object.